# Import existing Azure resource in Terraform Cloud

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, terraform-cloud

How can one import an existing Azure resource into Terraform cloud? Could not find an option for this in the web interface, but maybe I missed it?

Answer (score 1):

> How can one import an existing Azure resource into Terraform cloud?

You can use Import block for importing existing Azure resources into Terraform.

I have a resource group in my environment.

[image]

I Imported existing resource.

1. **Created config file**.

> ```
> provider  "azurerm" {
> features {}
>                      }
> resource  "azurerm_resource_group"  "example" {
> }
> ```

2. **Terraform Init**

```
terraform import azurerm_resource_group.example \
/subscriptions/SubscriptionNumber/resourceGroups/<ResourceGroupName>
```

Successful imported
[image]

**Terraform.tfstate file**
[image]

References taken from [azurerm_resource_group.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group)